# Slash in path to image in url() case webpack problem

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, webpack

I have Vue.js app and css style:

```
button.act { background-image: url('/res/img/done.svg'); }
```

When slash "/" is before path it works good on localhost, but on production server it casues 404 error because it's not an absolute path. Changing  to "./" works good on server but  on localhost caause error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './res/img/done.svg'
```

I use file-loader in webpack.config.js as below:

```
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
            }
          }
        ]
```

How can I change webpack config to get right path to image on localhost and on production server?

Comment: You could try `url('~@/res/img/done.svg')` assuming `res` is in your src folder. It's worked for me in similar contexts, but changing the webpack might be the more correct approach.

Comment: @OscarSchafer but how can I change webpack config? Unfortunately, your solutions doesn't work.